# Stuck in recurrence relation

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

$T(n) = 2 T\left(\dfrac{n}{2}\right) + n (\log_{2}n)^{2}, n > 1$

$T(1) = 1$

Note : $(\log_{2}n)^{2} = \log_2 n \times \log_2 n$

I have solve the above equation till the step

$T(n) = 2^{k} T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^k}\right) + n \sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} \left(\log_{2} \dfrac{n}{2^{i}}\right)^2$

However I am unable to solve 
$\sum_{i = 0}^{k-1} \left(\log_{2} \dfrac{n}{2^{i}}\right)^2$

Comment: Do you want the exact $T$ or an asymptotic approximation?

Comment: asymptotic approximation. I have to find the time complexity

Comment: WA says $$T_n=2 n \sum _{K[1]=0}^{-\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}-1}
   -\frac{\log ^2\left(2^{-K[1]}\right)}{2 \log
   ^2(2)}+n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making $n=2^z$ we have

$$
\mathbb T(z)=2\mathbb T(z-1)+2^z z^2
$$

with solution

$$
\mathbb T (z) = \frac 13 2^{z-1}\left(z+3z^2+2z^3+3C_0\right)
$$

and finally $\mathbb T (z)\to T(n)$

$$
T(n) = \frac n2C_0 + \frac n6 \log_2 n+\frac n2 (\log_2 n)^2+\frac n3(\log_2 n)^3
$$

NOTE

$$
\mathbb T (u) = T(2^u)
$$

$$
T(n) = T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right) =  T\left(2^z\right) = \mathbb T(z)
$$

Comment: Is the above T(z) is different from lower one. And if you have assume $n = 2^z$ then how is $T(n) = (differnet \, T)T(z)$

Comment: Please. See note attached.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Ansatz $T(n)=kn\log_2^3n$ so $$T(n)-2\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)=kn\left(\log_2^3n-(\log_2n-1)^3\right)\approx 3kn\log_2^2n,$$so take $k=\frac13$.

Comment: I couldn't understand how do you get it $T(n)$

Comment: @BrijRajKishore If my choice of Ansatz seems like it guesses too much of the correct answer, I suppose you could try $T(n)=kn^a\log_2^bn$.

Comment: Ansatz?? I have heard this term first time

Comment: @BrijRajKishore https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz